# How to login with Microsoft SSO in Cypress test when getting cookies blocked error

Tags: azure-active-directory, cypress, single-sign-on

I'm trying to login to microsoft SSO account in my cypress test and I'm getting "Your browser is currently set to block cookies." error. I am using Cypress version 10+. I've seen posts about using Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce() but it is deprecated in the 10+ version. This is the error I'm seeing in my cypress test:

[image]

This is how I'm trying to login.

```
cy.session(args, () => {
        cy.origin(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/`, {args}, ({ email, password}) => {
            cy.visit('/')
            cy.get('[name="loginfmt"]').type(email);
            cy.get('[name="passwd"]').type(password);
            cy.get('[type="submit"]').type('{enter}');
        })
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

// commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("jwtlogin", (name, password, token, path) => {
  const args = {
    name,
    password,
    token,
    path
  }
  cy.visit(Cypress.config('apiLoginURL'))

  cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false
  })
  cy.wait(7000)
  cy.get('.microsoft').click()
  cy.origin('https://login.microsoftonline.com', {
    args
  }, ({
    name,
    password,
    token,
    path
  }) => {
    cy.wait(17000)

    cy.get('body').then((body) => {
      if (body.find('#otherTileText').length > 0) {
        cy.contains('Use another account').click()
        cy.get('#i0116').type(name)
      } else {
        cy.get('#i0116').type(name)
      }
    })

    cy.get('#idSIButton9').click()
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.get('#i0118').type(password)
    cy.contains('Sign in').click()
    cy.get('div.tile:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)').click()
    cy.task("generateOTP", token).then(token => {
      cy.get("#idTxtBx_SAOTCC_OTC").type(token);
      cy.get('#idSubmit_SAOTCC_Continue').click()
      cy.wait(3000)
    })
    cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
      return false
    })




  })
  cy.wait(5000)
  cy.get('body').then((body1) => {
    cy.wait(5000)
    if (body1.find('#idBtn_Back').is(":visible")) {
      cy.wait(5000)
      cy.get('#idBtn_Back').click()
    }


    cy.wait(16000)
    


  })

})


//hooks file

before(() => {

  cy.origin('https://login.microsoftonline.com', () => {
    cy.visit('https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/logout')

  })
  cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {

    return false

  })
  cy.jwtlogin('testaccount.com', 'Derersr1', 'dfdfd', 'jeet.txt')
  cy.window().then(win => win.sessionStorage.clear());
  cy.clearCookies();
  cy.clearLocalStorage()

  cy.wait(11000)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when logging into Microsoft SSO in Cypress, the error message that appears is 'Your browser is currently set to block cookies,' even in cases where the actual reason for the error is something else. For instance, my account has been suspended and locked. In Cypress, the error message shows "Your browser is currently set to block cookies," but in my system's browser, it shows a different message.

This can be confusing, so it's important to keep in mind that the error message may not always accurately reflect the issue at hand.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

// cypress.config.js

```js
experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
  pageLoadTimeout: 180000,
  experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true,
```

Comment: Please combine the answers and explain what you are suggesting should be done.